# how to style fonts from a WordPress Object

Tags: angularjs, css

I am receiving an object from WordPress.

The main issue: when I go to the posts of WordPress in my app, all of them are with a different font, what should I do to style those fonts ?

[Here is a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CiZBXcwDGcOXUxlOduar?p=preview) just in case you want to try, click on any of the titles, that will take you to another view, there you will see what I am talking about.

This is the view where I need to style the fonts

```
<script id="tab-post-detail.html" type="text/ng-template">

        <div>
          <h3>{{:: post.title}}</h3>
          <p ng-bind-html=" post.content"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

</script>
```

[here you may see the Object](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed/)

Comment: give the `<div>` a class, maybe tab-post-item and style it in your CSS file

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your `<div>`:

```
<script id="tab-post-detail.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div class="tab-post-item">
    <h3>{{:: post.title}}</h3>
    <p ng-bind-html=" post.content"></p>
   </div>
  </div>

</script>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.tab-post-item h3 {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.tab-post-item p {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

You probably need to suffix every CSS entry with !important to override the inline style from the object.

Comment: won't over ride inline style

Comment: none of the inline style in the object have font styling, only width's and text-align's

Comment: That's just one example... content comes from a multitude of unknown wordpress sites as a feed

Comment: ah, okay. thats a lot of importants than ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since all the content comes from a multitude of individual unknown sites and can have any sort of inline style included you would need to be pretty aggressive to get it all to match a consistent styling in your app.

Important to realize that any wordpress blogger can apply any style to any element. In addition they may use tags like `<h1>` or `<h2>` that render much smaller than the norm due to styles in their themes but may look out of place within your app

---

Several potential options:

Write a targeted `css reset` using `!important` for all rules and properties. Would need to be fairly comprehensive and specific to the inner container the content is inserted into.

Or

Create a div outside of the dom and loop through all posts. Put the post content inside the created div and do a search for all elements with `style` attribute , and remove that attribute. Could work from available css resets and just add suffixes for your container

---

Second approach is likely the best (and least labor intensive) as far as knowing you are down to reasonably unstyled elements other than your own css. you may however need to use both approaches

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's directive `ng-style`

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for further details

I have updated the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nRBtPziUrGOaFN6mnO8d?p=preview

I added this to the controller, and then attached `ng-style = "mystyle"` to the relevant `<h1> <p>` tags

```
$scope.myStyle = {
    "font-family":"courier",
};
```

I set the font to courier, but obviously you can choose any font you like

Comment: why the post "More than" is still with the default fonts ? your method isn't working in this case.